# R: extracting subexpression occurrences from regular expression

Tags: regex, r

I want to extract few pieces of data from a string using a single regular expression. I made a pattern which includes these pieces as subexpressions in parentheses. In perl-like environment, I would simply pass these subexpressions to variables by code like `myvar1=$1; myvar2=$2;`, etc. - but how to do this in R?
 For the moment, the only way I found to access these occurrences is through regexec. It is not very convenient because regexec does not support perl syntax and for other reasons. This is what I have to do now:

```
getoccurence <- function(text,rex,n) { # rex is the result of regexec function
  occstart <- rex[[1]][n+1]
  occstop  <- occstart+attr(rex[[1]],'match.length')[n+1]-1
  occtext  <- substr(text,occstart[i],occstop)
  return(occtext)
}
mytext <- "junk text, 12.3456, -01.234, valuable text before comma, all the rest"
mypattern <- "([0-9]+\\.[0-9]+), (-?[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+), (.*),"
rez <- regexec(mypattern, mytext)
var1 <- getoccurence(mytext, rez, 1)  
var2 <- getoccurence(mytext, rez, 2)  
var3 <- getoccurence(mytext, rez, 3)
```

Obviously, it is quite clumsy solution, there should be something much better. I would appreciate any advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you had a look at `regmatches`?

```
> regmatches(mytext, rez)
[[1]]
[1] "12.3456, -01.234, valuable text before comma," "12.3456"                                      
[3] "-01.234"                     "valuable text before comma"                   

> sapply(regmatches(mytext, rez), function(x) x[4])
[1] "valuable text before comma"
```

Comment: ouch, indeed! I have of course read regmatches' description but somehow overlooked this :( Thank you so much!!!

Comment: P.S. now I see why: I tried to use regmatches only after regexpr, not after regexec...

Answer (score 1):

In `stringr`, this is `str_match` or `str_match_all` (if you want to match every occurrence of the pattern within a string.  `str_match` returns a matrix, `str_match_all` returns a list of matrices

```
library(stringr)
str_match(mytext, mypattern)
str_match_all(mytext, mypattern)
```

Answer (score 1):

`strapply` and `strapplyc` in the [gsubfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) can do that in one step:

```
> strapplyc(mytext, mypattern)
[[1]]
[1] "12.3456"                    "-01.234"                   
[3] "valuable text before comma"

> # with simplify = c argument
> strapplyc(mytext, mypattern, simplify = c)
[1] "12.3456"                    "-01.234"                   
[3] "valuable text before comma"

> # extract second element only 
> strapply(mytext, mypattern, ... ~ ..2)
[[1]]
[1] "-01.234"

> # specify function slightly differently and use simplify = c
> strapply(mytext, mypattern, ... ~ list(...)[2], simplify = c)
[1] "-01.234"

> # same
> strapply(mytext, mypattern, x + y + z ~ y, simplify = c)
[1] "-01.234"

> # same but also convert to numeric - also can use with other variations above
> strapply(mytext, mypattern, ... ~ as.numeric(..2), simplify = c)
[1] -1.234
```

In the examples above the third argument can be a function or as in the examples a formula which gets converted into a function (LHS represents arguments and RHS is body).